# How can assign numbers based on percentile in R?

Tags: r

I have this column in a dataframe, df:

```
10
12
75
89
25
100
67
89
4
67
120.2
140.5
170.5
78.1
```

I am trying to

1. Calculate the 10%,20%,30%,...,90% percentile values of the range of df.
2. Assign a value of 1-10 based on which percentile the values fall in. (eg. if 10 is in the 20%-30% percentile range of df, I assign a value of 2 that is stored  in a different column.

Basically, I am trying to create an output like this (These values are rough estimates, not based on actual percentiles)

```
10      2
12      2
75      4
89      5 
25      3 
100     6 
67      4
89      6
4       1
67      5
120.2   7
140.5   8
170.5   10
78.1    5
```

I don't know how to create these percentiles and assign values.

So far I have only been able to do this

```
quantile(df, c(.1, .2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9))
```

Could you please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's somewhat unclear how you were calculating your breaks based on your example, but from your description, this should work

```
x<-c(10, 12, 75, 89, 25, 100, 67, 89, 4, 67, 120.2, 140.5, 170.5, 78.1)
qq<-cut(x, breaks=seq(min(x),max(x), length.out=11), include.lowest=T, labels=F)
```

Here we take the vector and split it into 10 groups with `seq(min(x),max(x), length.out=11)` (thereby using the range of observed values) so the groups are

```
1: 4-26.65
2: 20.65-37.30
3: 37.30-53.95
....
10: 170.50-153.85
```

And then we just use the `cut` command with those breaks to create the new IDs to get

```
 # cbind(x, qq)
          x qq
 [1,]  10.0  1
 [2,]  12.0  1
 [3,]  75.0  5
 [4,]  89.0  6
 [5,]  25.0  2
 [6,] 100.0  6
 [7,]  67.0  4
 [8,]  89.0  6
 [9,]   4.0  1
[10,]  67.0  4
[11,] 120.2  7
[12,] 140.5  9
[13,] 170.5 10
[14,]  78.1  5
```

If you actually wanted to use quantiles, you could use

```
qq<-cut(x, breaks=quantile(x, seq(0,1, length.out=11)), include.lowest=T, labels=F)
```

which would give

```
          x qq
 [1,]  10.0  1
 [2,]  12.0  2
 [3,]  75.0  5
 [4,]  89.0  7
 [5,]  25.0  3
 [6,] 100.0  8
 [7,]  67.0  4
 [8,]  89.0  7
 [9,]   4.0  1
[10,]  67.0  4
[11,] 120.2  9
[12,] 140.5 10
[13,] 170.5 10
[14,]  78.1  6
```

Comment: Oh,, the output numbers are just a rough estimate. Checking your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, is this code breaking the data evenly? I don't want that. I actually have a very long series and would like to use percentiles. I may have misunderstood your code as well though...I am confused about seq(min(x),max(x), length.out=11)

Comment: Well, I tried to get something close to your sample output. The fact that is was just a rough guess was not clear and quite misleading. I've updated the answer to also include using quantiles. But yes, the first version creates 10 evenly sized bins along the range of x.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I have added the addendum. Apologies for that.

Comment: Hi, one question. In the same problem, I also have to assign the weights in the reverse order. i.e. 10 for 0-10%, 2 for 80-90% etc. How could I do it?

Comment: Uhm, just take `11-qq`.

Comment: An emoticon of gratitude and embarrassment.

Comment: One small question, when I do this to add to the original dataframe: df<-cbind(x, 11-qq), how can I name the column right there? I want to name the column qq instead of 11-qq. I can do it in a different line, but I was wondering if I could do it on the fly.

Comment: If you have questions that are different than the one originally described, it's best to start a new question rather than open new issues in the comments. That way other people can see them and can respond. That being said, you can name it in the cbind with `all<-cbind(x, weight=11-qq)`.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to this forum. Will do from now.

Answer (score 3):

This is one option:

```
d <- read.table(text="10
12
75
89
25
100
67
89
4
67
120.2
140.5
170.5
78.1")

transform(d, percentile=findInterval(V1, quantile(V1, seq(0,1, by=.1))))

# HEAD:
# 
#   V1 percentile
# 1 10          1
# 2 12          2
# 3 75          5
# 4 89          7
# 5 25          3
# 
#   ---  4  rows omitted ---
# 
# TAIL:
#       V1 percentile
# 10  67.0          4
# 11 120.2          9
# 12 140.5         10
# 13 170.5         11
# 14  78.1          6
```

Comment: Hi, In the same problem, I also have to assign the weights in the reverse order. i.e. 10 for 0-10%, 2 for 80-90% etc. How could I do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your values are in `x`, I would do something like

```
 floor((x-min(x)) / (max(x)-min(x)) *10)
```

The fraction `(x-min(x)) / (max(x)-min(x))` says how far into the range we are. The denominator `(max(x)-min(x))` gets the range, in this case `170.5 - 4 = 166.5`. The numerator `x-min(x)` calculates how far into the range we are.

We then multiply by `10` and round down to get you a number between `0` and `10`.

```
> floor((x-min(x)) / (max(x)-min(x))*10)
 [1]  0  0  4  5  1  5  3  5  0  3  6  8 10  4
```

This gives different results to what you gave in your example, but with the lowest number being `4`, then for example `10` clearly falls into the `0` to `10%` category not the `20` to `30%` category.

---

Edit: if you're interested in the *order* of the values, you can do

```
floor(rank(x) / length(x) * 10)
```

`rank` gives

```
2.0  3.0  7.0  9.5  4.0 11.0  5.5  9.5  1.0  5.5 12.0 13.0 14.0  8.0
```

and then you divide by the length (`14`) and similarly to the above multiply by `10` and use `floor`

```
> floor(rank(x) / length(x) * 10)
 [1]  1  2  5  6  2  7  3  6  0  3  8  9 10  5
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the `data.table` way which is much much faster:

```
library(data.table)
d = data.table(V1 = c(10, 12, 75, 89, 25, 100, 67, 89, 4, 67, 120.2, 140.5, 170.5, 78.1))
d[, percentile:= findInterval(V1, quantile(V1, seq(0,1, by=.1), na.rm=T))]
```